# How to remove the link from all parent elements and clone them as a child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, touch

Because mobile devices do not have a hover state, I am trying to remove the links on the first il elements every time these have children, and clone them as children of themselves (with link).

```
<ul id="menu-header-menu">

    <!--this li has children so link should be removed -->
    <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://url.com/porfolio">Portfolio</a> 
        <ul class="sub-menu">
             <li><a href="http://url.com/paint">Painting</a></li>
             <li><a href="http://url.com/vid">Video</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>

    <!--this li doesn't have children so link should NOT be removed -->
    <li><a href="http://url.com/about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

And I want to do the same in the footer menu:

```
<ul id="menu-footer-menu">

    <!--this li has children so link should be removed -->
    <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://url.com/links">Links</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="http://url.com/doc">Documents</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://url.com/ext">Extra</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://url.com/photo">Photos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <!--this li doesn't have children so link should NOT be removed -->
    <li><a href="http://url.com/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am generating this html structure through php on a WordPress website so I am trying to avoid element ID's.

I am trying this jQuery script, but it clones both li onto both menus (header and footer) so I end up with two clones of each, one in each menu.

```
if($(window).width() <= 980){
    $('ul#menu-footer-menu').each(function() {
        $(this).find('a:first').clone().appendTo( "ul.sub-menu" );
        $(this).find('a:first').contents().unwrap();
    }); 
    $('ul#menu-header-menu').each(function() {
        $(this).find('a:first').clone().appendTo( "ul.sub-menu" );
        $(this).find('a:first').contents().unwrap();
    });
}
```

Could give me a hand?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it. I just needed to target the right place to append the cloned li.

```
if($(window).width() <= 980){
    $('ul#menu-footer-menu').each(function() {
        $(this).find('a:first').clone().appendTo( "ul#menu-footer-menu > li.menu-item-has-children > ul.sub-menu" );
        $(this).find('a:first').contents().unwrap();
    }); 
    $('ul#menu-header-menu').each(function() {
        $(this).find('a:first').clone().appendTo( "ul#menu-header-menu > li.menu-item-has-children > ul.sub-menu" );
        $(this).find('a:first').contents().unwrap();
    });
}
```